# ACTION_VIEW intent result

Tags: android

If I want to open file, passing it's URI in an intent and `ACTION_VIEW`, but I don't know if there is app that supports such file, can I know whether file was opened or not?

Comment: [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/can-i-use-this-intent.html) explains the code snippet Kevin Yuan posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static boolean canIntentBeHandled(final Context ctx, final Intent intent) {
  final List<ResolveInfo> info = ctx.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
  return info.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: If i don't know the name of Intent, I just now that's just pdf file and ACTION_VIEW. Can include mime-type to intent?

Comment: ACTION_VIEW is OK, you can include mime-type. Just do this test after you construct the intent for your pdf viewing and before startActivity().